# r - Adding rows by group so that every group has at least n observations

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, as.date

I'm working with a data frame that is structured like the following:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2010-02-01", "2010-03-01", "2010-04-01", 
"2010-05-01", "2010-06-01"), class = "factor"), y = c(1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), binary = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))


        Date  y binary
1  2010-02-01 1      0
2  2010-03-01 1      0
3  2010-04-01 1      0
4  2010-02-01 2      0
5  2010-03-01 2      0
6  2010-04-01 2      0
7  2010-05-01 2      1
8  2010-06-01 2      1
9  2010-02-01 3      0
10 2010-03-01 3      1
```

I'm trying to make it so every group has **at least** four consecutive, month by month observations, with the condition that once the binary assumes value = 1 for a group, it stays that way. The results should look like this:

```
         Date   y binary
>1  2010-02-01  1   0
>2  2010-03-01  1   0
>3  2010-04-01  1   0
>4  2010-05-01  1   0
>5  2010-02-01  2   0
>6  2010-03-01  2   0
>7  2010-04-01  2   0
>8  2010-05-01  2   1
>9  2010-06-01  2   1
>10 2010-02-01  3   0
>11 2010-03-01  3   1
>12 2010-04-01  3   1
>13 2010-05-01  3   1
```

I've created a subset of the data for the first group (y = 1), for which the following loop works.

```
dt1 <- dt[1:3,]
maxdate<- 0
while(nrow(dt1) < 5){maxdate <- as.Date(dt1[nrow(dt1), 1])  %m+% months(1) ;  dt1<- rbind(dt1, c(as.character(maxdate) , dt1[nrow(dt1),2], dt1[nrow(dt1),3]))}
```

But I don't how to incorporate this function into a dplyr structure like  `dt %>% group_by(y)`.

How do I obtain my result, preferrably with dplyr, and, if possible, without recurring to for loops?(actual data set is very large).

Answer (score 4):

Here is one option, where we first convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, grouped by 'y', get the number of rows (`n()` per group), then use that info to expand the 'Date' in `complete` so that there is atleast 4 rows per group, `fill` the `NA` elements with the previous non-NA and remove the temporary 'n' column created

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
   group_by(y) %>% 
   mutate(n = n()) %>%
   complete(Date = seq(first(Date), length.out = max(first(n), 4),
           by = '1 month')) %>%
   fill(binary) %>%
   select(-n)
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   y [3]
#      y Date       binary
#   <dbl> <date>      <dbl>
# 1     1 2010-02-01      0
# 2     1 2010-03-01      0
# 3     1 2010-04-01      0
# 4     1 2010-05-01      0
# 5     2 2010-02-01      0
# 6     2 2010-03-01      0
# 7     2 2010-04-01      0
# 8     2 2010-05-01      1
# 9     2 2010-06-01      1
#10     3 2010-02-01      0
#11     3 2010-03-01      1
#12     3 2010-04-01      1
#13     3 2010-05-01      1
```

Comment: Thank you! This was amazignly helpful.
I've noticed using `na.locf()` from the zoo package is a much more efficient way to fill out the remaining columns than `fill()`, and gets the job done within seconds, rather than days.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a new table of all the dates you want, then do a rolling join of that to your original table `df`, then `nafill` other columns as needed.

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, Date := as.Date(Date)]

alldts <- 
  df[, if(.N < 4) .(Date = first(Date) + months(0:3)) else Date,  by = y]

df[alldts, on = .(y, Date), roll = -Inf
   ][, binary := nafill(binary, 'locf')][]

#           Date y binary
#  1: 2010-02-01 1      0
#  2: 2010-03-01 1      0
#  3: 2010-04-01 1      0
#  4: 2010-05-01 1      0
#  5: 2010-02-01 2      0
#  6: 2010-03-01 2      0
#  7: 2010-04-01 2      0
#  8: 2010-05-01 2      1
#  9: 2010-06-01 2      1
# 10: 2010-02-01 3      0
# 11: 2010-03-01 3      1
# 12: 2010-04-01 3      1
# 13: 2010-05-01 3      1
```